# Specific unit output using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Consider the following example.

I would like to use the `\SI` command from [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to type the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent What I have:
\[
  \SI{6.67384(80)e-11}{\N\square\m\per\square\kg}
\]
What I would like:
\[
  \num{6.67384(80)e-11}\,\si{\N\square} \cdot (\si{\m/\kg})^{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The current situatuion is that you can'd do this directly using the tools in the package.

Comment: Is the desired output consistent with SI's specifications?

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure. `:(` I just made the assumption that it is possible with `siunitx`, considering the versatility of the package.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg With respect to consistency, please have a look at "SI Unit rules and style conventions", available at  http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html.

Comment: @Papiro Good point. Even though it seems it be against the rules and conventions, I would like to have it as explained. Can it be done with `\SI`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg If you want a 'general solution', how should cases such as `\N\cubic\m\per\square\kg` be handled [I will add a feature request, but want to know what I'm being asked for :-)]

Comment: @JosephWright Hmmm. I haven't really thought about that. An idea would be to be abel to parse some specific option(s) to `\SI` to get the output as, e.g., `(m/kg)²` instead of `m²kg⁻²`.

Comment: @JosephWright Maybe a key `group-power` taking a number `n` which makes all units with the power `n` and `-n` to be grouped into such a parentheses. Then there would be a key `group-negative-powers` with the default value `true` meaning the behaviour the OP asked for, the value `false` meaning the powers `-n` are ignored and the value `on their own` meaning something like (m*kg)^2/(s*V)^2 or (m*kg)^2/(s*V)^{-2}. Lastly a key `group-all-powers` which does `group-power` for all `n`>1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, Joseph is wrong. You can do this very easily with `siunitx`, although it seems a bit unaesthetical:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\myunit}{(m/kg)}
\begin{document}
\[
\SI{6.67384(80)e-11}{\N\myunit\squared}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I meant that you can't auto-format from `\N\square\m\per\square\kg`.

Comment: Even if there were some functionality involved, no software could completely auto-format out of this given input, because markup is missing. How should the software know, which units should be inside the brackets and which not?

Comment: The question doesn't make it explicit, but I was working on the assumption that the brackets were meant to cover 'units raised to the same power'.

Comment: @JosephWright It is indeed meant to cover units raised to the same power.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: What reason is there behind grouping units with the same power? It seems to me, that in general it's more important to have compound units with special meanings like m/s^2 or eV. Creating them is possible with SIunitx. In this example, there is only one caveat: What if you want that compound unit m/kg singularly and therefore without parentheses?